# Is there an excel function calculate future value of constant payments at variable interest rate

Tags: excel-formula

Known that:

1. FV function: future value of constant payments at constant interest rate
2. FVschedule function: future value of no payments at variable compound interest

My task is to calculate the future value of constant payments at variable interest rate.

Say the principal is 10,000. Annual rate is 5%. Tenor with 2 monthly period starting at Jan. The periodic payment in arrear is 1,300.

Interest for Jan is calculated as (10,000 * 5% * 31 / 360 = 43) The principal repaid is (1,300 - 43) = 1,257.

Interest for Feb is calculated as ((10,000-1,257) * 5% * 28 / 360 = 34) The principal repaid is (1,300 - 34) = 1,266.

The future value (aka balloon payment) would be 10,000 - 1,257 - 1,266 = 7,477.

So I would like to know if there is a formula could calculate **7,477** by inputting the above data, rather than calculate the whole repayment schedule each time.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is such a function. There is however a way how to approach this in an excel-like manner. As you correctly anticipated, excel is just the right tool for that, as it can re-calculate the whole repayment schedule each time, many times a second.

First, collect the parameters like that to the columns K & L

[image: parameters]

Second, create a table with the schedule. First column label Date and it will be the date of the last days of the months. Lets assume that you start with the first day of the current month, so the first row will be

```
=EOMONTH($L$6;[@Period])
```

where $L$6 is the cell with start date. The next column [@Period] has just the count of the schedule periods, i.e. 1,2,3,4... as many as you like. You can use formula

```
=ROW()-1
```

for that.

Next column label Days with formula

```
=DAY([@Date])
```

That is for calculating the effective interest rate.

Next column label Aliquote with formula

```
=[@Days]/$L$2
```

with the effective interest rate for the current period (month).

Now it gets interesting. The next columns label B/O for the beggining of month outstanding amount

```
 =$L$4-SUM(G$1:G1)
```

and copy/past for the next rows. It calculates the outstanding amount based on the principal parameter stored in L4 by subtracting the sum of Amortizations in the column G we create next.

Next column is then labeled interest

```
 =$L$3*[@Aliquote]*[@[B/O]]
```

where L3 refers the parameter with the nominal interest rate.

and the next column is labeled Amortization

```
=$L$5-[@Interest]
```

calculated from the periodic arrears stored in L5.

The last column is labeled C/O for the close of the month outstanding amount.

```
=[@[B/O]]-[@Amortization]
```

If you have done it correctly, it shows you the C/O values running towards zero and then of course negative in the 8th period onward. You can change the parameters to get adjust it for the scenario you need.